# Relate the User table to a Tweet table in Springboot with PostgresSql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postman

I want to relate the User table that is made with jwt, that is, when I create a user I get a token but I want to relate it when I create an object in the Tweet table I want to relate it to the User but I don't know how to assign it

Actually I just want the method that helps me relate it. I already have the complete crud but I don't have a way to relate it.

Comment: You'll need to explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help with your issues, but there are certain expectations on you. Please spend a few minuets to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. 
 Then update your question to include sample data, table definition (ddl scripts), the expected results of that data and what you have tried, all as text - **no images**; also adding a  [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) is extremely useful. Further clearly describe what you are attempting and where you are having issues.